# Android app cannot access server files anymore

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have php script which i access from app (its located on my server) and it checks login details and then log in to app.
Few days ago it stopped working on all Android devices below 5.0,it cant get any response from that files.
Im using volley library for android for requests to server.

I havent changed anything in app or on server manually,idk what could that be?

Here are logs im getting:

```
06-18 22:24:57.730 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake fd=0x1f500005 shc=0x20f00009 timeout_millis=2500 client_mode=1 npn=0x0
06-18 22:24:57.731 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
06-18 22:24:57.731 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x10 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.732 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 handshake start in UNKWN  before/connect initialization
06-18 22:24:57.732 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.732 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.733 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:UNKWN  before/connect initialization
06-18 22:24:57.733 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.734 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.734 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:23WCHA SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
06-18 22:24:57.734 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.735 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=-1
06-18 22:24:57.739 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:error exit in 23RSHA SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
06-18 22:24:57.739 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.740 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=-1
06-18 22:24:57.740 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=11 sslError=2 timeout_millis=2500
06-18 22:24:57.741 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: sslSelect type=READ fd=60 appData=0x533629a8 timeout_millis=2500
06-18 22:24:57.874 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: sslSelect READ fd=60 appData=0x533629a8 timeout_millis=2500 => 1
06-18 22:24:57.874 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
06-18 22:24:57.877 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.877 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:3RSH_A SSLv3 read server hello A
06-18 22:24:57.877 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.879 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x53e12a48 arg=0x0
06-18 22:24:57.880 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
06-18 22:24:57.905 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 cert_verify_callback => 0
06-18 22:24:57.905 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.906 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:3RSC_A SSLv3 read server certificate A
06-18 22:24:57.906 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.909 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.909 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:3RSKEA SSLv3 read server key exchange A
06-18 22:24:57.909 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.909 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.909 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:3RSD_A SSLv3 read server done A
06-18 22:24:57.909 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.930 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.930 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:3WCKEA SSLv3 write client key exchange A
06-18 22:24:57.930 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.934 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.934 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:3WCCSA SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
06-18 22:24:57.934 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.934 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.940 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:3WFINA SSLv3 write finished A
06-18 22:24:57.942 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.943 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1001 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.943 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:3FLUSH SSLv3 flush data
06-18 22:24:57.944 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.944 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=-1
06-18 22:24:57.944 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:error exit in UNKWN  SSLv3 read server session ticket A
06-18 22:24:57.945 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.945 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback where=0x1002 ret=-1
06-18 22:24:57.945 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 SSL_connect:error exit in UNKWN  SSLv3 read server session ticket A
06-18 22:24:57.946 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 info_callback ignored
06-18 22:24:57.946 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=-1
06-18 22:24:57.946 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake exception => 0
06-18 22:24:57.946 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x53353358 NativeCrypto_SSL_interrupt
06-18 22:24:57.947 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto:  sslNotify, appData=0x533629a8 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.947 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb D/NativeCrypto:  sslNotify, appData=0x533629a8 ret=1
06-18 22:24:57.960 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb I/System.out: [CDS]close[48163]
06-18 22:24:57.963 20031-20201/com.example.edb.edb I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:48163]
06-18 22:24:58.402 20031-20074/com.example.edb.edb I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x51a92e58) fps:50.20, dur:1015.92, max:29.88, min:12.78
06-18 22:24:59.410 20031-20074/com.example.edb.edb I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x51a92e58) fps:48.57, dur:1008.75, max:40.08, min:16.76
06-18 22:25:00.420 20031-20074/com.example.edb.edb I/SurfaceTextureClient: [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x51a92e58) fps:50.50, dur:1009.86, max:33.87, min:5.38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My SSL Certificate Expired so i had to change all links from "https" to "http"